# Is replacing elements in a list equivalent to removing then inserting elements? Or simply accessing them?

Tags: python, list, time-complexity

I am trying to figure out if `replacing items in a list` is `equivalent` to `removing the items then inserting`? - in which case it would be O(n) time, whereas I know accessing elements in a list is constant time, so would replacing elements be O(1)?

```
For example, nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 

temp = [8,8,8]

nums[2:5] = temp 

print(nums) 

-> [1,2,8,8,8,6]
```

Would this be an O(1) operation or O(n)? Or something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CPython (the "official" reference implementation that most people use), the [algorithm](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6082bb5addab93755ab6e2bd2ed6021b391e10d1/Objects/listobject.c#L687) is roughly as follows (omitting irrelevant details):

```
# a[ilow:ihigh] = v

norig = ihigh - ilow
n = len(v)
d = n - norig
if d < 0:
    move a[ihigh:] to a[ihigh + d:]
    resize a to len(a) + d
elif d > 0:
    resize a to len(a) + d
    move a[ihigh:] to a[ihigh + d:]
```

That means, if you're replacing a slice by another slice of equal length, no items in the original list are actually moved. So the operation is O(*k*) where *k* is the length of the replacement slice, irrespective of the total length *n* of the original list.

On the other hand, if you manually remove a slice and then insert another, the items after the removed ones will actually need to be moved, so you're getting O(*n* + *k*) time complexity instead.

Note that this is a CPython implementation detail, but I would be very surprised if other Python implementations worked less efficiently.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this makes completed sense. One more question, so is it correct to say that as long as the slice that I am using to replace items in the list, is shorter than the list itself, then it is O(k), since I am not 'resizing' the list?

Comment: I.e. as long as I am not resizing the list, then replacing a slice with a slice is O(k).

Comment: It's only O(_k_) if the replacement slice is exactly as long as the slice you're replacing. If the replacement is shorter, all elements following the slice will need to be moved backwards in memory, incurring an O(_n_) operation where _n_ is the length of the original list, for a total of O(_n_ + _k_).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, could you briefly explain why it is O(n+k) rather than just O(n)? Because in my mind in the worst case the slicing happens at the start of the list, and so all of the items after the slice need to be moved forward by however many steps- so how does the length of the slice k play a part in the complexity?

Comment: The length of the slice _k_ needs to be added because after moving the original _n_ elements, you still need to copy the _k_ elements of the slice into place.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Python documentation [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html#time-complexity):

> ## Time Complexity
>
> O(k) for slice retrieval
> O(n) for deletion
> O(n+k) for slice assignment

So that means that slice assignment (what you're asking about) is `O(n+k)`.

Comment: The document you are linking to is old, and not official (the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#list) don't mention time complexity at all though). In this case, because the slice is replaced by a slice of equal length, an optimization would be possible that allows for O(k) assignment.

Comment: Okay, so am I right in assuming that replacing elements in the list, is the equivalent of deleting then inserting into the list?

Comment: Say I was to do a 'replacement' for each item in the list, would it then be O(n^2)?

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is O(1) (or O(k) where k is the length of your slice)

```
a = list(range(100))
b = list(range(100000))

timeit.timeit('a[50] = 10', globals=globals(),number=10000)
0.00039079999999103165
timeit.timeit('b[50] = 10', globals=globals(),number=10000)
0.00039970000000266737
timeit.timeit('b[5000] = 10', globals=globals(),number=10000)
0.0003963999999996304
timeit.timeit('b[5000:5005] = [10,11,12,13,14]', globals=globals(),number=10000)
0.0016413999999826956
 timeit.timeit('a[50:55] = [10,11,12,13,14]', globals=globals(),number=10000)
0.0016435999999657724
```

Comment: Thank Eumel, when would it be O(1) and when O(k)? What is this dependent on?

Comment: @hfddhudfhs That might have been worded badly, its always O(1), but slices are not processing in bulk so if you slice its gonna almost take the time as if you had replaced the values one by one. In my examples that would have been `k=5`